# Multiple rows values into one row value. Is there a better solution to go about this?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

What I am trying to do is to consolidate multiple rows of data into one row based on ID.

The issue I was having is that I need the old data and the new data combined based a condition. 
The condition is, if there is no row value, the address stay the same, if there is a value then change the data according to whatever the property is.

I have tried STUFF AND FOR XML PATH for String Concatenation and using case statement but I wasn't able to get the desired result I wanted. BTW I am fairly green so I probably didn't use it correctly.

I have provided the link below on how I was able to solve this problem.
It has been a long day and I probably overthinked it. I wanted to reach out to you professionals on what you think and what may be a better alternative?

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/df574d/4/0

Data Sample

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[AddressUpdate]
(
[ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[AddressUpdateID] [int] NOT NULL,
[Property] [varchar](50) NULL,
[OldValue] [varchar](max) NULL,
[NewValue] [varchar](max) NULL,
)

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Address]
(
[ID] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[AddressUpdateID] [int] NOT NULL,
[Address] [nvarchar](256) NULL,
[City] [nvarchar](256) NULL,
[State] [nvarchar](256) NULL,
[Zip] [nvarchar](256) NULL,
[CountryCode] [nchar](3) NULL,
)

INSERT INTO Address
(
--Address.ID,
AddressUpdateID,
Address,
[City],
State,
Zip,
CountryCode
)
VALUES
( 1, '654 5th Ave', 'Los Angelas', 'LA', '65445', 'USA'),
( 2, '123 Broadway Ave', 'Orlando', 'FL', '56476', 'USA'),
( 3, '789 Sunset Lane', 'Oakley', 'Alberta', 'L6H 0P7', 'CAN'),
( 4, '987 Country Dr', 'Flint', 'MI', '89874', 'USA'),
( 5, '741 Fast Street', 'MONTREAL', 'Quebec', 'T8V 0N5', 'CAN')


INSERT INTO AddressUpdate
(
--ID
AddressUpdateID,
Property,
OldValue,
NewValue
)
VALUES
(1, 'Address', '654 5th Ave', '5321 Hollywood'),
(2, 'Address', '123 Broadway Ave', '654 West Village'),
(2, 'City', 'Orlando', 'New York City'),
(2, 'State', 'FL', 'New York'),
(2, 'Zip', '56476', '8642'),
(4, 'Address', '987 Country Dr', '987 Maple Rd'),
(4, 'City', 'Flint', 'Alberta'),
(4, 'State', 'MI', 'GRANDE PRAIRIE'),
(4, 'Zip', '89874', 'T8V 0N5'),
(4, 'CountryCode', 'USA', 'CAN')
```

How I solved it.

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#temp') IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
DROP TABLE #temp
END

CREATE TABLE #temp
(
AddressUpdateID BIGINT,
Address     NVARCHAR(256),
City        NVARCHAR(256),
State       NVARCHAR(256),
Zip         NVARCHAR(256),
CountryCode NCHAR(3)
)


INSERT INTO #temp (AddressUpdateID)
SELECT      
        DISTINCT a.AddressUpdateID
FROM 
        Address a


--update address
UPDATE #temp 
SET #temp.Address = au.NewValue
FROM AddressUpdate au
WHERE au.addressupdateid = #temp.AddressUpdateID
AND au.property = 'Address'


--SELECT * FROM #temp
--update null address with current value
UPDATE #temp
SET #temp.Address = a.Address
FROM Address a 
WHERE #temp.Address IS NULL AND #temp.AddressUpdateID = a.AddressUpdateID

--update city
UPDATE #temp 
SET #temp.City = au.NewValue
FROM AddressUpdate au
WHERE au.addressupdateid = #temp.AddressUpdateID
AND au.property = 'City'

--update null city with current value
UPDATE #temp
SET #temp.City = a.City
FROM Address a  
WHERE #temp.City IS NULL AND #temp.AddressUpdateID = a.AddressUpdateID

--update state
UPDATE #temp 
SET #temp.State = au.NewValue
FROM AddressUpdate au
WHERE au.addressupdateid = #temp.AddressUpdateID
AND au.property = 'State'

--update null State with current value
UPDATE #temp
SET #temp.State = a.State
FROM Address a 
WHERE #temp.State IS NULL AND #temp.AddressUpdateID = a.AddressUpdateID

--update zip
UPDATE #temp 
SET #temp.Zip = au.NewValue
FROM AddressUpdate au
WHERE au.addressupdateid = #temp.AddressUpdateID 
AND au.property = 'Zip'

--update null zip with current value
UPDATE #temp
SET #temp.Zip = a.Zip
FROM Address a  
WHERE #temp.Zip IS NULL AND #temp.AddressUpdateID = a.AddressUpdateID

--update country code
UPDATE #temp 
SET #temp.CountryCode = au.NewValue
FROM AddressUpdate au
WHERE au.addressupdateid = #temp.AddressUpdateID
AND au.property = 'CountryCode'

--update null country code with current value
UPDATE #temp
SET #temp.CountryCode = a.CountryCode
FROM Address a 
WHERE #temp.CountryCode IS NULL AND #temp.AddressUpdateID = a.AddressUpdateID


SELECT  
        [Old Address] = a.Address + ' ' + a.City +', ' + a.State + ' ' + a.Zip + ' ' + a.CountryCode
        ,[New Address] = t.Address + ' ' + t.City +', ' + t.State + ' ' + t.Zip + ' ' + t.CountryCode

FROM    
    Address a
LEFT JOIN #temp t ON t.AddressUpdateID = a.AddressUpdateId
```

Comment: Can't reach you sql fiddle

Comment: Please edit your question and put the required information in the question -- sample data and desired results.  SQL Fiddle is really, really helpful, but the question should also contain the information.

Comment: Can you please include sample data and desired output in question. SQLFiddle has too much of information. I couldn't identify the problem area.

Comment: Yes, I am trying to figure out how to put that out there now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`UNPIVOT` the `Address` table first and `JOIN` it in the `AddressUpdate`. After that, use `FOR XML PATH('')` for string concatenation:

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/df574d/5/0)

```
;WITH CteAddressUnpivot(Id, AddressUpdateId, Property, Val) AS(
    SELECT
        a.Id,
        a.AddressUpdateID,
        x.Property,
        x.Val
    FROM Address a
    CROSS APPLY( VALUES
        ('Address', Address),
        ('City', City),
        ('State', State),
        ('Zip', Zip),
        ('CountryCode', CountryCode)
    )x(Property, Val)
)
SELECT
    OldAddress  = a.Address + ' ' + a.City +', ' + a.State + ' ' + a.Zip + ' ' + a.CountryCode,
    NewAddress  = x.NewAddress 
FROM Address a
CROSS APPLY(
    SELECT STUFF((
        SELECT ' ' + ISNULL(au.NewValue, cau.Val)
        FROM CteAddressUnpivot cau
        LEFT JOIN AddressUpdate au
            ON au.Property = cau.Property
            AND au.AddressUpdateID = cau.AddressUpdateId
        WHERE
            cau.Id = a.ID
        FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
    , 1, 1, '')
)x(NewAddress)
```